# Get 26 dates of every thursday starts from next week from current date sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the date of every thursday starts from next week and so on independent of the date of current week (Only first 26 entries are required).

Let's for example if today is thursday (13-June-2017) then next dates would be

> 1. (20-June-2017)
> 2. (27-June-2017)
> 3. (03-Aug-2017) and so on.

This will be same for selection of any day of current week (09-June-2017 - 15-June-2017) (Sunday-Saturday)

Comment: and so so = until what date, end of universe? just find next thursday and add 7*n days to it, n=1..how many do you want

Comment: I need 26 entries

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 DECLARE @ThrusdayList TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY
    ,DATES DATE
    )
DECLARE @counter INT
DECLARE @Date DATE

SELECT @counter = 0

SELECT @Date = '20170713' --Add your date

WHILE @counter <= 52
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @ThrusdayList (DATES)
    SELECT Thursday = convert(VARCHAR(11), DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Date), 120)

    SELECT @counter = @counter + 1

    SELECT @Date = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Date)
END

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),DATES,113) AS Thursdays
FROM @ThrusdayList
```

Comment: No if we change input date to Tuesday it will returns all Tuesdays

Comment: @Peter Did you checked it

Comment: Yes i did, I entered 20170711 and the first 'thursday' is 18 jul 2017. Not Thursday 20 jul 2017 as in the example

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
-- get all dates between 2 points
declare
    @EndDate datetime

set @EndDate=DATEADD(month,6,getdate())

SELECT 
    [date]=convert(datetime, CONVERT(float,d.Seq))
FROM 
    (
    select top 100000 row_number() over(partition by 1 order by A.name) as Seq 
    from syscolumns A, syscolumns B  
    )d 
where
    convert(datetime, CONVERT(float,d.Seq))>GETDATE() and 
    convert(datetime, CONVERT(float,d.Seq))<=@EndDate and
    datename(dw,convert(datetime, CONVERT(float,d.Seq))) ='Thursday'
```

You need an 'end date' no doubt so added variable as an example but lots of ways to do that

Comment: This only works if the current day is thursday to saturday, not if current day is sunday to wednesday.

Comment: @Peter Hi. Maybe I misunderstood the question. This lets them get all Thursdays into the future (assuming a 6 month 'end' point).

Answer (score 0):

You can use temporary tally table to generate this dates as below:

```
Declare @date date = '2017-06-13'

Select top(26) Dates = DateAdd(day, 7*(Row_Number() over (Order by (Select Null))), @date) from
    master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2
```

Another approach, You can use Recursive CTE as below as well:

```
Declare @date date = '2017-06-13'

;with cte_dates as (
    Select @date as Dt, 1 as Levl
    Union ALL
    Select Dateadd(day, 7, Dt) as Dt, Levl+1 as Levl from cte_dates
        where Levl < 26
)
Select * from cte_dates
```

Answer (score 0):

use "7-datepart(dw,@mydate)+5" to find the thursday next week, then use the recursive part to find the next thursdays.

```
declare @mydate datetime = dateadd(day,-4,getdate())

;with Thursdays_rte as
(
    select dateadd(day,7-datepart(dw,@mydate)+5,@mydate) thursday, 1 rn
    union all 
    select dateadd(week,1,thursday),rn+1
    from Thursdays_rte
    where rn < 26
)

select thursday,datename(dw,thursday)
from thursdays_rte
```

Answer (score 0):

I took Kannan's solution and just modified it to ensure that you were getting the correct start date:

```
declare @dt date
declare @nDay int
set @dt = '07/12/17'

select @nDay =  datepart(dw,@dt)
print @nDay
IF @nDay > 5 
    SET @dt = DATEADD(day,(@nDay - 5) * -1,@dt)
else
    SET @dt = DATEADD(day, 5 -@nDay ,@dt)

--BECAUSE ROW_NUMBER STARTS AT 1 SET THIS BACK A WEEK TO GET THIS WEEK
SET @dt = DATEADD(day, -7 ,@dt)

Select top(26) Dates = DateAdd(day, 7*(Row_Number() over (Order by (Select Null))), @dt) from
    master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @dw int = 5; /*Thursday. put here your day of week as int*/

    with nums as /* generate 26 values */ 
    (
    select number as n
    from master..spt_values
    where type = 'p'
    and number between 0 and 25
    )
    select dateadd(day, 7 * n, start_day)
    from nums cross apply
           (
           select
                   case 
                      when datepart(dw, getdate()) <= @dw
                      then dateadd(day, @dw - datepart(dw, getdate()), cast(getdate() as date))
                      else dateadd(day, 7 +  @dw - datepart(dw, getdate()), cast(getdate() as date))
                   end as start_day /* find the first dw = @dw after today */
           )a;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to put some upper limit on this.  SQL Server will not return infinite series.  But this should give you an idea:

```
declare @cnt int = 7
declare @thursdays table
(
    thursday date 
)
while @cnt < 100
    begin
        INSERT INTO @thursdays VALUES( cast(DATEADD(dd,@cnt,getdate()) as date))
        set @cnt = @cnt + 7
    end

SELECT * FROM @thursdays
```

Comment: This will only work if the current day is a thursday.